# working with arraytype in spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My requirement is to cast all Decimal data type in DataFrame to String. Logic is working fine with simple type but not working with ArrayType.
Here is logic :-

```
var df = spark.sql("select * from test_1")
for(dt <- df.dtypes) {
  if(dt._2.substring(0,7) == "Decimal"){
    df = df.withColumn(dt._1,df(dt._1).cast("String"))  
  }
}
```

But column within arrayType remains unchanged although, they are decimal type. please help , how can I loop through nested element and cast it to string.
This is schema of my dataframe:

> scala> df.schema res77: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType =
>   StructType(StructField(mstr_prov_id,StringType,true),
>   StructField(prov_ctgry_cd,StringType,true),
>   StructField(prov_orgnl_efctv_dt,TimestampType,true),
>   StructField(prov_trmntn_dt,TimestampType,true),
>   StructField(prov_trmntn_rsn_cd,StringType,true),
>   StructField(npi_rqrd_ind,StringType,true),
>   StructField(prov_stts_aray_txt,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(PROV_STTS_KEY,DecimalType(22,0),true),
>   StructField(PROV_STTS_EFCTV_DT,TimestampType,true),
>   StructField(PROV_STTS_CD,StringType,true),
>   StructField(PROV_STTS_TRMNTN_DT,TimestampType,true),
>   StructField(PROV_STTS_TRMNTN_RSN_CD,StringType,true)),true),true))

Comment: You have to write a UDF which convert the each decimal In array to string.it because the type of the column is array of decimal

Comment: Can you share sample code for this requirement? I am looking for UDF which implements this task.

Comment: Even I know that, I will require a UDF which will iterate through Array Elements, and cast all Decimal types to String. But I don't know how to write that code. Hence, looking for sample code(UDF) for same.

Comment: you want to change all the data in prov_stts_aray_txt column to change to string ? is that so?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan , Only fields with decimal type in prov_stts_aray_txt, has to be converted to String. I tried a lot, but couldn't find any clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using spark 2.1 and above then following casting should work for you

```
val newSchema = DataType.fromJson(df.schema.json.replaceAll("(decimal\\(\\d+,\\d+\\))", "string")).asInstanceOf[StructType]
df.select(newSchema.map(field => col(field.name).cast(field.dataType)): _*)
```

which should cast all the decimal types to string type.

But if you are using spark version lower than the mentioned and since there is *timestamp* datatype in the struct column you will encounter

> > `TimestampType (of class org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType$)
> >     scala.MatchError: TimestampType (of class org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType$)`

Its a [casting structs fails on Timestamp fields](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16791) and resolved [cast struct with timestamp field fails](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/14400)

Comment: One more help in same line that I can iterate over flat fields and perform operation such as replace. But again it's not iterating through nested fields. How can I iterate over fields including nested field and perform expression as desired... Thanks in advance..

Comment: above solution is going to every decimal datatype, even in the nested struct and array types. I confirmed it myself before I answered :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also cast complex types, e.g. if you have a dataframe like this schema:

```
root
 |-- arr: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- i: decimal(22,0) (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- j: double (nullable = false)
```

you can cast all array-elements of type decimal (field `i` n this example) by doing:

```
df
  .select($"arr".cast("array<struct<i:string,j:double>>"))
  .printSchema()

root
 |-- arr: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- i: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- j: double (nullable = true)
```

EDIT:
If you don't know the schema in advance, you can just replace the `decimal` in the original schema with `string`:

```
val arraySchema = df.schema.fields(0).dataType.simpleString
val castedSchema = arraySchema.replaceAll("decimal\\(.*\\)","string")

df
  .select($"arr".cast(castedSchema))
  .show()
```

Comment: This is not my requirement. I have to loop through elements of arrayType, and cast all Decimal type to String Type...

Comment: @Vinitkumar and why exactely do you NEED to loop?

Comment: I have to cast all Decimal types to String. And there are fields which are Decimal within ArrayType.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (your comparison with == is probably not what you want)

```
var df = spark.sql("select * from test_1")
for(dt <- df.dtypes) {
  if("Decimal".equalsIgnoreCase(dt._2.substring(0,Math.min(7, dt._2.length)))){
    df = df.withColumn(dt._1,df(dt._1).cast("String"))  
  }
}
```